# Cofused with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

`re.findall(r'(\w)*','2sq')`

Why is the result of this programme is: `['q', '']`?

I thought it would be `['2','s','q',' ']`.

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w','2sq')` will yield `2`, `s`, `q`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the * and you'll get the expected result.  * is a greedy, looks like you want each \w and findall will do that.